# How to implement a last resort physical reset button for resetting kiosk app?

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk, watchdog

I have a kiosk app which runs on a dell 760 machine running ubuntu 14.04 server with a touch screen. The kiosk app is running in a browser and the system is locked down (chrome is running in kiosk mode).

Sometimes it could happen that there will be an unknown error and the app might freeze or might need restarting. Since there is no keyboard or anything else, I want to implement a physical button (to be located in the back of the kisok) which the attendant can use to reset/restart the app.

Physically restarting the machine (using the power button) accomplishes this but restarting the whole machine just to restart a browser is...

Can anyone suggest how I can connect a simple push button to either the serial, parallel port or USB port of the machine so that when this push button is pressed a listening bash script could just restart the chrome browser?

I know there are some custom made boards/products that could be plugged into the usb port ([https://www.amazon.com/Dream-Cheeky-902-Electronic-Reference/dp/B004D18MCK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004D18MCK)) but I need to implement this with simple things that are available on hand. I do not have easy access to online shops or anything like that. I need to do this in the simplest way, either using whatever is already on the machine or using something as simple as a push button (which I have lying around). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am setting up kiosk machines for a project and the best way to do it is to install OpenSSH on the kiosk machine.  When the browser locks up you or someone can SSH into the machine and reboot it or stop/start Chrome from the terminal.  You could probably script the restart on the users machine so all they have to do is double-click to get it to run.